# What is the identity of this 4-wide car bumper part from a photo?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone tell me what part this is?

[image: 1 x 4 wide rear bumper]

Answer (score 12):

It's [[Part 50949] Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Racers Car Grille](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=52180)

[image: Rendering from BrickLink]